# Javascript Nested map iteration do not update my Object's Value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with Nested Maps.
I need to update a data after an axios response but my value is not passing to the main container
here is my code

```
        let abc = usr.map(updatedNode=> {
            JSON.parse(updatedNode.orderDetail).map(orderProduct=> {
                axios.get(appUrl +'productDetail/'+orderProduct.id)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        orderProduct.productTypes.map(opt => {
                            JSON.parse(response.data[0].productTypes).map(node => {
                                if(node.id == opt.id){
                                    delete opt['quantity']
                                    delete node['quantity']
                                    opt.quota = node.quota
                                }
                            }) 
                            return opt;
                        })
                    })
                    return orderProduct
                })
                return updatedNode
            })
           res.send(abc);
```

This code should update the quota amount but where it is updated in 'updatedNode' in outside I can't see the updated value
Where am I doing wrong ?

EDIT
my usr.json below ;

```
[
{
id: "cbc9b288-36f5-4e45-a75a-9c75f9a8287c",
orderDetail: "[{"productTypes":[{"id":1,"productType":"S-M-LA","productTotalPrice":"35","quota":38,"productSubPiece":3,"value":5,"quantity":[{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3},{"value":4},{"value":5},{"value":6},{"value":7},{"value":8},{"value":9},{"value":10},{"value":11},{"value":12},{"value":13},{"value":14},{"value":15},{"value":16},{"value":17},{"value":18},{"value":19},{"value":20},{"value":21},{"value":22},{"value":23},{"value":24},{"value":25},{"value":26},{"value":27},{"value":28},{"value":29},{"value":30},{"value":31},{"value":32},{"value":33},{"value":34},{"value":35},{"value":36},{"value":37},{"value":38}]},{"id":2,"productType":"S-M","productTotalPrice":"75","quota":3,"productSubPiece":2,"value":"","quantity":[{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":2},{"value":3}]}],"id":"productID","productName":"SONpR","productName_ru":"prSon","picture":"PICTURE"}]",
orderType: "PENDING",
userId: "8f9c623c-98ce-4904-a5b7-2d5fc68a7f5e",
createTime: "2020-07-16T18:30:42.000Z",
lastUpdate: "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
name: "NAME"
}
]
```

orderDetail is string so I am parsing it to JSON then trying to manipulate the date

Comment: What does `updatedNode` look like?

Comment: almost like the usr.json nothing is updated besides opt. opt values are correct but its not being updated in outer maps

Comment: What type of object is it?

Answer (score 0):

Is updatedNode a mongodb resultset or something ? It if is, first convert it to JS object.

```
let obj = updatedNode.toObject();
```

Than work with obj variable.

Comment: Shared my JSON file too. its a json result so I dont need to convert it to obj or smth. the thing is where I can see the correct result in return updatedNode line I can not see in the end

Comment: You problably cant because some result objects are immutables (like mongodb objects). I had the same issue many times, and most of them was a mistake like this. Take a try.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Array.map does not accept Promise which is what's happening now.
You can combine all api calls, wait for it and then process using map.

```
async function abc(usr) {
  const promises = []
  usr.forEach(updatedNode => {
    JSON.parse(updatedNode.orderDetail).forEach((orderProduct) => {
      promises.push(axiom.get(`${appUrl}productDetail/${orderProduct.id}`))
    })
  })
  const resArray = await Promise.all(promises)
  const abc = resArray.map(response => {
    orderProduct.productTypes.map(opt => {
      JSON.parse(response.data[0].productTypes).map(node => {
        if(node.id == opt.id){
          delete opt['quantity']
          delete node['quantity']
          opt.quota = node.quota
        }
      }) 
      return opt;
    })
  })
}
```

You might want to tweak a bit to get your result.

Comment: Thnaks! Guess i will be moving from that solution. yes the problem is using promise inside array.map

Answer (score 0):

Because you are making multiple api calls you could use `Promise.all()` and then manipulate your data any way you like also note that the array of user info posted has syntax error.

Your code should look something like this

```
Promise.all(usr.map(updatedNode=>JSON.parse(updatedNode.orderDetail).map(orderProduct=>
  axios.get(appUrl +'productDetail/'+orderProduct.id)))).then(p=>console.log(p) // manipulate your data here )
```